# CakePHP compared to Joomla

Tags: php, cakephp, joomla

So the past month ive been working alot with CakePHP getting to know the conventions also getting better at the MVC structure and how it works.

Now in cakephp you basicly bake Model views and controllers where Models are assoiciated to Database tables and controllers handle the request back and forward from the Model and the view.

Now Joomla is build in a different way. As far as ive understood Joomla is build up of modules and components but these components and modules follow the MVC structure.

Now to my Question:

How close is cakephp programming to Joomla programming like how does it compare? is creating components and modules the exact same thing as creating Models and Controllers in cake (execpt from the Api calls not being the same)?

Comment: Check out http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_(general_definitions) and figure what it would require to create this functionality in CakePHP...

Comment: @ndm thanks my goal is actually take make Joomla applications

Comment: Joomla is a CMS while a framework. The fact that they both follow the MVC pattern (like so many other systems too) isn't a denominator that you can rely on. You simply have to try. MVC can come in many flavors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Joomla Framework has its own MVC just like all frameworks.  If you develop applications on that it is somewhat different than what you would do building an extension inside the CMS.

Building an extension on the Joomla CMS is different from building an application on the framework and I really would separate that out and figure out what you want. IF you want to build on the CMS because htat give you user management, authentication, cache etc and then you build on top of that, it is a different than than building a stand along application.

So you really need to figure out which it is you want to do.